# javascript timer in gridview asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my product table i have a start date and end date. I want to show a countdown timer in my asp.net gridview such that when it expires it will show "Project Ended"

It is showing: But how do i remove hard coded date to pick the date from the sql database. Also, with the hard coded date it is only showing once in the first row of my gridview table.
**This is the aspx page:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="ProjectID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" PageSize="50" GridLines="Vertical">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <Columns>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S/N" HeaderStyle-Width="100">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                    </ItemTemplate>

<HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="100" ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CssClass="glyphicon-edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
            &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="ProjectID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProjectID" />

                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Project Title" SortExpression="ProjectTitle">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="projectT" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProjectTitle")%>' Height="48px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="735px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProjectTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProjectTitle") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" SortExpression="StartDate" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="EndDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" SortExpression="EndDate" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Duration" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Duration" SortExpression="Duration" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectCost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="ProjectCost" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:N}" SortExpression="ProjectCost" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Currency" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="Currency" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PercentageOfCompletion" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="% of Completion" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:P}" SortExpression="PercentageOfCompletion" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhaseType" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="PhaseType" SortExpression="PhaseType" >

<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Type" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Type") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectTypeID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectTypeID") %>' DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="ProjectTypeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>



                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" SortExpression="StateName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="StateName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StateName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="StateID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("StateID") %>' DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="StateID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LGA" SortExpression="LGName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LGName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LGName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="LGAID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LGAID") %>' DataTextField="LGName" DataValueField="LGAID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Community" SortExpression="CommunityName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="CommunityName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CommunityName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="CommunityID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CommunityID") %>' DataTextField="CommunityName" DataValueField="CommunityID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company" SortExpression="CompanyName">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="CompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="CoyID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CoyID") %>' DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CoyID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contractor" SortExpression="Company">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Company" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ContractorID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ContractorID") %>' DataTextField="Company" DataValueField="ContractorID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProjectStatusID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectStatusID") %>' DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ProjectStatusID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Year" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Year") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="YearID" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("YearID") %>' DataTextField="Year" DataValueField="YearID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectExistence" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Proj Existence" SortExpression="ProjectExistence" >


<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                 </asp:BoundField>

                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Project Relevance" SortExpression="ProjectRelevance">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="projectrelevance" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProjectRelevance")%>' Height="204px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="735px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ProjectRelevance" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("ProjectRelevance") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="Remarks">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="remark" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Remarks")%>' Height="204px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="735px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="remark01" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Remarks") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CountDown">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div id="myCountdownClass"><%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("EndDate").ToString()) ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") : "" %></div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

This is my script:

```
<script>
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 5, 2017 15:37:25").getTime();

        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function () {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now an the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            document.getElementById("myCountdownClass").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

            // If the count down is finished, write some text 
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("myCountdownClass").innerHTML = "PROJECT ENDED";
            }
        }, 1000);

    </script>
```

Comment: If I were you i'd start looking for a jQuery countdown timer. Refreshing the entire page every second just to show a countdown is a huge server load.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks. Now using jquery countdown. How do i fetch date automatically from sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick demo of how to create a countdown timer in a GridView. Use a `TemplateField` and place the correct date in a div. Add a class to that div so you can reference it in jQuery.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="myCountdownClass"><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") %></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the jQuery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.myCountdownClass').each(function () {
        var date = $(this).text();
        $(this).countdown(date, function (event) {
            $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

This demo uses this as the countdown timer: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

UPDATE

To prevent errors when converting to datetime when the database value is `null,` use a ternary operator.

```
<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("myDate").ToString()) ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") : "" %>
```

UPDATE 2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="myCountdownClass"><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") %></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.myCountdownClass').each(function () {
        var date = $(this).text();
        $(this).countdown(date, function (event) {
            $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I am having this challenge, some of my End Date column in my database is null. Hence, i am getting this error message "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." How do i set a condition  to bypass that and still give me the countdown for those that have a date in the End Date column in my database.<div class="myCountdownClass"><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy") %></div>

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate answer. I appreciate. My gridview is now showing. But the countdown column is having the end date displaying in it instead of the countdown timer showing and ticking as supposed.What do i do?

Comment: Try debugging with a fixed date `var date = "2017/01/01"` (2017/01/01 is from the authors page). If that works you know it an incorrect date format due to regional settings. Or there could be Javascript errors so check the console. And because i did not wrap the script in a `$(document).ready(function () { });`, make sure the gridview is above the script.

Comment: this is what i saw at the console: 
jquery.countdown.js:27 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.countdown.js:27
    at jquery.countdown.js:29
(anonymous) @ jquery.countdown.js:27
(anonymous) @ jquery.countdown.js:29
youu.aspx:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at youu.aspx:21

Comment: I am grateful for your help. But I wish you could take a look again at the code inside the templatefield. Is it working at your own end?

Comment: I thank you. Please can you still help me out? I am yet to hear from you.

Comment: There is not much I can do. It all works as it should on my end so you'll have to figure out why it is not working on yours. Did you add `jquery.countdown.min.js` to your project?

Comment: yes i inserted it at the header and the script below the gridview

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD. I am in West Africa(Nigeria). Can you give a screenshot of your working screen and script?

Comment: Added a complete snippet and an image. There is no code in code behind except for filling the GridView of course.

Comment: thank you. still not coming up. For the class which is 'myCountdownClass' is it a default? or how do i locate my own class in the jquery script?

Comment: Thanks for your concerns in helping me out. I just updated my gridview and script. I tried that and it is showing. But i want to remove the hard coded date in the script to pick date from sql database. And also with the hard coded date it only displays once in the gridview may be because i have not changed it to pick its date from the database. Please help me out.

Comment: Please help me out with the update on my script. I appreciate you

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: is quite unfortunate that you can give up so easily in helping me out.